# XPath: path if current node has special tag

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml and I am using lxml in python

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>
        <message>pick/me</message>
    </bar>
    <bar>
        <message>not/me/though</message>
    </bar>
<foo>
```

I iterate over "bar" containers, and only want to select a certain subset of them based on a direct child. I tried the code below.

My python code is

```py
lst_my_bar = root.xpath("bar")
for my_bar in lst_my_bar:
    nodes_to_select_try1 = my_bar.xpath('[message/text()="pick/me"]') # does not work
    nodes_to_select_try2 = my_bar.xpath('./[message/text()="pick/me"]') # does not work
    nodes_to_select_try3 = my_bar.xpath('.[message/text()="pick/me"]') # does not work
```

Comment: Try escaping "/" with "\" like `pick/\me`

Comment: @AmbrishPathak: No, escaping `/` within a string there is wrong.  Additionally, you got the wrong recommendation backward as well, further confounding the confusion you're sowing.  Just delete your comment, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at the `bar` axis, try using the following XPath:

```
message[text()="pick/me"]
```

resulting in the python command

```
nodes_to_select_try1 = my_bar.xpath('message[text()="pick/me"]')
```

which should select the corresponding `message` elements.
Maybe you have to adjust your initial command to

```
lst_my_bar = root.xpath("/foo/bar")
```

to get to the `bar` axis.

Comment: It's unclear what OP's end goal is, but perhaps suggest a direct XPath without bothering with a loop in the hosting language:  For example, `//bar[message="pick/me"]` will select all `bar` elements with the targeted `message` child elements.